# how to pass the value to jquery from views in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a requirement where i need to show the new form in the same window where we have listed the items and also the edit form in the same page. I have run

```
rails generate scaffold Item name:string
```

which by default created all that is needed and now i made use of jquery to show the new form in the index page itself on clicking a text but how can i make the edit form to appear in the same page. What i need to know is how can i send the id on clicking to jquery and get the form populated with the value. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you should try inline editing [RailsCast : InlineEditing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast). Rather than going for jquery and ajax manually.

And for same page having new form : [Using Ajax With RJS](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs)